# JavaScript How do i set my volumeSlider to the latest value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

JavaScript

```
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer'); 
var volumeSlider = document.getElementById('volumeSlider');   
mutePlayer.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var mutePlayer = document.getElementById('mutePlayer');
  var playMute = document.getElementById('playMute');

  if(videoPlayer.muted) {
    videoPlayer.muted = false;
    playMute.src = "img/mute.png";
    volumeSlider.value = 100; /** THIS IS THE PROBLEM RIGHT NOW I HAVE JUST SET IT TO 100 */
  } else {
    videoPlayer.muted = true;
    playMute.src = "img/unmute.png";
    volumeSlider.value = 0;
  }
});
volumeSlider.addEventListener('change', function() {
  videoPlayer.volume = volumeSlider.value / 100;
});
```

This code has to be the current value of the #volumeSlider

I have tried this but i cant access the variable volumeSlider since its scoped?

```
volumeSlider.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var volumeSlider = volumeSlider.value;
  return;
});
```

The HTML5

```
<video id='videoPlayer' class="videoPlayer" width="640px" height="360px">
  <source id="Video" src="vid/bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" height="360px" width="640px">
</video>
<button id='mutePlayer'class="center" >
  <img id='playMute' src='img/mute.png'>
</button>
<input id='volumeSlider'class="center" type="range" min='0' value='100' step="1"></input>
```

Can someone help me crack this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of reasons why your code wont execute correctly. If you want to change a global variable in a scope, you don't want the `var` in front of the variable name.

What I've changed in the code is that the default value gets set to 100, but when I click on the slider sets inputs value to the value that's clicked on. The code will look like this:

```
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer'),
mutePlayer = document.getElementById('mutePlayer'),
playMute = document.getElementById('playMute'),
volumeSlider = document.getElementById('volumeSlider'),
durationTimeText = document.getElementById('durationTimeText').innerHTML = "01:00",
videoPlayerVolume = 100;

volumeSlider.value = 100;

mutePlayer.addEventListener('click', function() {
if (videoPlayer.muted) {
    volumeSlider.value = cachedVolume;
    videoPlayer.muted = false;
    playMute.src = "img/mute.png";
} else {
    cachedVolume = volumeSlider.value;
    videoPlayer.muted = true;
    playMute.src = "img/unmute.png";

    volumeSlider.value = 0;
  }
});

volumeSlider.addEventListener('change', function() {
    videoPlayerVolume = volumeSlider.setAttribute('value', this.value);
    if (volumeSlider.value > 0) {
        playMute.src = "img/mute.png";
    }
});
```

I also added a small feature for you that sets the button image to the mute image, if the value of the input is over 0 which means that it's not muted.

If you're questioning the `this` keyword, it takes the element that gets clicked on and replaces it with itself. You can read more about the `this` keyword [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

I hope it helped.

Comment: Iam still very new to JavaScript, how do i put the value that i get inside this part of the code -> volumeSlider.value = 100;

Comment: I've changed the answer not - try to take a look at it and see if it makes sense to you and if it solves your problem.

Comment: I tried to copy paste the the code but videoPlayerVolume is not defined ?

Comment: I have uploaded the videoplayer here -> http://www.chri126g.wigf1.sde.dk/videoplayer also can you tell me why the volume is not following the click? if i click half volume and mute/unmute when the unmute goes to 100value again the volume is not all the way up? and first when the play button is pressed the duration shows?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking about why the slider goes back up to 100, when you unmute it and not to the value that was set before you muted it. I've changed the code up a bit, so it changes back to the value that was set previously. I hope that was the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Hej Christian, koden virker dog stadig ikke :/

1) Første problem
Hvis jeg trykker på 20 på volume knappen og trykker mute går den på 0 og unmute så går den på 100 ikke 20

2) Volume knappen
Hvis jeg sætter volume knappen på 20 og trykker på mute knappen, og så unmute går den på 100value men lyden er ikke 100value, hvis jeg trykker lige ved siden af på fx 90 så går lyden op?

3) Tiden
Først når jeg trykker play viser duration tiden? har presat det til 00:00 og 00:00 men den opdatere først til 00:00 01:00 når jeg trykker play

Comment: Hej Christian. Jeg har taget et nærmere kig på det, og har nu fået cached den værdi, så sliderens værdi går tilbage til det, som den var før, den blev muted. Jeg har derudover også angivet duration til at være 01:00, som du ønsker.

Comment: Nu virker det men lyden går dog ikke op/ned når jeg scroller volumeSeek op/ned :D amen altså :D

Comment: du kan se resultatet af dit kode her, når man slider til 0 går lydbilledet hellere ikke til mute :) chri126g.wigf1.sde.dk/videoplayer

Comment: Prøv at tage et kig på https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video. Her kan du eventuelt anvende attributen "controls" til at tilføje start/pause knapper, lydniveauer, etc.